# Error in adding dependency - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android library in my android project. I tried adding it into my project by "**compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:0.3.0'**" as mentioned on its page and it works perfectly in my project.

I wish to do some custom changes in that library. So I tried cloning the sample project over there and it is working fine.

But when I try to add the "richeditor" project folder from the sample code in my code and add "**compile project('libs:richeditor')**" in my app build.gradle and also add "include '**:app:libs:richeditor'**" in settings.gradle, it throws me an error **"Error:Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found."**.

P.S. I have put the richeditor project in **app/libs/** folder.

How to solve this error or is there any other way I could make some custom changes to the above library?

build.gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
    compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.2.jar')
    compile project('libs:richeditor')
    compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
}
```

build.gradle (richeditor)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    task("javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + "/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
    }

    task("bundleJavadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar) {
        description "Bundles Javadoc into zip for $variant.name."
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from tasks["javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}"]
    }
}

apply from: 'android-artifacts.gradle'
apply from: 'central-publish.gradle'
apply from: 'bintray-publish.gradle'
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Have you remove the original dependency on the external version?  Could you post a snippet from your build.gradle file?

Comment: I get the Error - Error:Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found. And I have updated the question by posting both the gradles of app as well as the richeditor. In the external version I only changed the sdk and build tool version.

Comment: does the version of richeditor that you've created in the app/libs folder build on its own?

Comment: No. I took that from the sample project from github and put it in app/libs.

Comment: I think you will need to get that project building before your android build will work, because your main gradle build will also try and build it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jay there is issue on classpath

see the file [bintrya-public.gradle](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/blob/master/richeditor/bintray-publish.gradle)

the file apply the plugin **'com.jfrog.bintray'**
whose classpath is defined in the file [build.gradle](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/blob/master/build.gradle)
(whose scope is outside of the project/module 'richeditor')

**Solution -**

Import the module, then

1. Add

> classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.3.1'

into the build.gradle file of project under dependencies

2. Add the below lines into gradle.properties file of project

> VERSION_NAME=1.0.0 VERSION_CODE=16 GROUP=jp.wasabeef
>   ARTIFACT_ID=richeditor-android COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=23
>   BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.2 TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23 MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
>   POM_DESCRIPTION=RichEditor for Android is a beautiful Rich Text
>   WYSIWYG Editor POM_URL=https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android
>   POM_SCM_URL=git@github.com:wasabeef/richeditor-android.git
>   POM_SCM_CONNECTION=git@github.com:wasabeef/richeditor-android.git
>   POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:wasabeef/richeditor-android.git POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
>   POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
>   POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo POM_DEVELOPER_ID=wasabeef
>   POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Wasabeef
>   POM_DEVELOPER_EMAIL=dadadada.chop@gmail.com
>   POM_DEVELOPER_URL=wasabeef.jp
>   ISSUE_URL=https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/issues
>   SUPPORT_PACKAGE_VERSION=23.0.1

now, sync the project and enjoy the import

Comment: Hey perfect answer and explanation for the above error. This perfectly worked fine. I had put the above properties but din't mention the classpath in the build.gradle(outside app).

Answer (score 0):

Change from **"compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:0.3.0'"** to **compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.0.0'** in build.gradle

See this link: https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android#gradle

Comment: Even with the older version I am able to run. But I wish to change the library code as per some custom requirement. So I copied the 'richeditor' folder from the sample application. But unable to add that as dependency. Is there any way I could write some custom code in above library?